# Possible to create a class that has a default value

Tags: php

I was wondering if there is a way to create a class in PHP that when compared with other variables a default value is used instead of the class itself?  such that:

```
class Test {
    private $name;
    private $val;
    public function __construct($name, $val) {
       $this->name = $name;
       $this->val = $val;
    }
    public __default() {
        return $val;
    }
    public function getName() {
        return $name;
    }
}
```

then I could use a function like `__default` when I compare it to another value such as:

```
$t = new Test("Joe", 12345);
if($t == 12345) { echo "I want this to work"; }
```

the phrase "I want this to work" will print.

Comment: I cannot use PECL but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement [__toString()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) in your class.

Like:

```
class myClass {
    // your stuff

    public function __toString() {
        return "something, or a member property....";
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried __toString but had no luck, but then tried it again and it actually did work on comparison this time after a few tries, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not possible. The closest thing you're looking for is the __toString() method to be set on the class.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

PHP might try to convert it to an Integer, but I'm not sure if there are class methods to accomplish this. You could try string comparison.

```
<?php
class Test {
    private $name;
    private $val;
    public function __construct($name, $val) {
       $this->name = $name;
       $this->val = $val;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return (string)$this->val;
    }

    public function __toInt() {
        return $this->val;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

$t = new Test("Joe", 12345);
if($t == '12345') { echo "I want this to work"; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately _toInt isn't a real magic method. I put it there for testing.

Comment: It should be as far as i'm concerned.

Comment: Looks like it was a feature request but it was rejected https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48076

Answer (score 1):

The `__toString` magic method will do what you want with some caveats:

```
class Test {
    private $name;
    private $val;
    public function __construct($name, $val) {
       $this->name = $name;
       $this->val = $val;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->val;
    }
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Objects can't be directly cast to an integer so will always get a when comparing to an integer but if you cast either side of the comparison to a string it will work as expected.

```
if($t == 12345)          // false with a warning about can't cast object to integer
if((string)$t  == 12345) // true
if($t == "12345")        // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object will unlikely equals integer. But you can implement something similar to Java's `hashCode()` - a class method that do some math to produce numeric hash - a return value based on i.e. its internal state, variables etc. Then compare these hash codes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something along this line:

```
class Test {
    private $name;
    private $val;
    public function __construct($name, $val) {
       $this->name = $name;
       $this->val = $val;
    }
    public __default() {
        return $val;
    }

    public compare($input) {
        if($this->val == $input)
            return TRUE;
        return FALSE;
    } 

    public function getName() {
        return $name;
    }
}

$t = new Test("Joe", 12345);
if($t->compare(12345)) { echo "I want this to work"; }
```

From other answers it appears there is not a built in function to handle this.

Comment: because I want it to be seamless that the properties that will be used are still values, but yet I can trace back what class and property they came from.